# Android listview not displaying data

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to set up my listview however I can not get it to display the data, im sure I am missing something but here is my code:

my xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#95dad4"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editdate_top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:text="@string/selectholidaytxt"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:textColor="#8e3a41"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/countryspinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editdate_top"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editdate_top"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editdate_top" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/holidayslist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/countryspinner"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/countryspinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/countryspinner" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#42c1b6" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settings_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/home"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/settingicon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/settings_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/homeicon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/settings_btn"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/settings_btn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settings_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/infoicon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#42c1b6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back_btn" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my activity:

```
public class Listing extends Activity {

    ListView holidays;
    ArrayList<String> DataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_holidayslisting);

        holidays = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.holidayslist);

        DataList.add("test");
        DataList.add("test2");
        DataList.add("test3");
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DataList);

        holidays.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

However the listview shows nothing.

Comment: post your full xml layout

Answer (score 0):

it's simple. You have to populate your spinner so that your spinner has some width to it. Since you don't do anything to it, the width of your spinner is zero and you have these attributes to your ListView

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/countryspinner"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/countryspinner"
```

which aligns the width of the listview to spinner's width.

You either remove the above attributes from ListView or hard code a width to your spinner, or populate your spinner with some values.

Layout should be like this,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editdate_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:textColor="#8e3a41"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/countryspinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editdate_top"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editdate_top"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editdate_top" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/holidayslist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/countryspinner" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#42c1b6" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/home"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/settings_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/settings_btn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/settings_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settings_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#42c1b6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Changed to ` <ListView
            android:id="@+id/holidayslist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/countryspinner" >` but still not displaying